# Вызывать catch не по коду ответа HTTP

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Всем привет! Дело в том, что API, с которым я работаю, возвращает всегда status code 200. Но в содержимом может быть `{"status": "error", "reason": "No money"}`, как мне заставить автоматически вызывать rejection callback в Promise? Возможно ли это? или только если использовать проверку при каждом запросе и throw? Возможно у axios есть какие-то способы изменить проверку на ошибку, сделать её не по коду HTTP?
Пример кода:

```
axios.get('/user', {
  params: {
    ID: 12345
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться [`interceptors`](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors), позволяют добавить методы для реквеста/респонса для всех вызовов `axios`

```
  axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    if(response.data.status === 'error') return Promise.reject('Ваша ошибка');
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Comment: Ого, спасибо вам большое!!! То, что нужно!

Comment: Только тут надо обращаться к response.data, и в Promise.reject(error) не объявленная переменная error

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать это с помощью перехватчика, который обработает запрос и сможет сделать вернуть промис reject

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  if (response.data.status === 'error') {
    return Promise.reject(response.data.reason);
  }

  return response;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!